# Error de authentication con Postgres en A2 Hosting

Tags: php, postgresql, hosting

Tengo problemas para establecer la conexion a `Postgres` con PHP sea por la funcion  `pg_connect` o con `PDO` intente de las siguientes manera sin exito alguno;

primer intento:

```
$db_connection = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=levantiu_levantium user=levantiu_levantium_app password=mypassword");
```

segundo intento:

```
$dsn = "pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=levantiu_levantium";
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false, // turn off emulation mode for "real" prepared statements
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, //turn on errors in the form of exceptions
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, //make the default fetch be an associative array
];
try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, "levantiu_levantium_app", "mypassword", $options);
    echo 'conectado!';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
    exit('Something weird happened'); //something a user can understand
}
```

ambos intentos obtengo error de authentication;

Un intento extra fue acceder al servidor mediante `SSH` pero en este caso si accedí a la base de datos sin problemas con las mismas credenciales;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Segui las siguientes guias para descartar algun error humano;

https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/cpanel/cpanel-database-features/managing-postgresql-databases

https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/postgresql/connect-to-postgresql-using-php

Actualmente estoy usando PHP 7.3 en el servidor. He cambiado de versión y no obtengo ningún resultado distinto.

Error al intentar conectar:

**Fue resuelto el problema por el soporte técnico del hosting;**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La cadena de conexión completa debería parecerse a esto: `pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=testdb;user=bruce;password=mypass`, tú no le estás pasando el nombre de usuario. Intenta con algo así:  **`$pdo = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=$dbname;host=$host", $dbuser, $dbpass, $options); `** sustituyendo adecuadamente cada valor. [Ver el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-pgsql.connection.php) para más detalles. Muestra en la pregunta el mensaje específico de error que imprime para revisarlo.

Comment: @A.Cedano también tengo una configuración como esta, tampoco funciona, obtengo el mismo error, incluso copie su código para descartar cualquier problema. Continuo obteniendo el mismo problema de authentication

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar en la pregunta el mensaje de error completo que muestra? Gracias.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo he agregado, de igual manera, este es mi archivo test http://levantium.a2hosted.com/test/testconection.php

Comment: Mágicamente se ha resuelto!!!!!!!! pero por dios!!! jajaja

Comment: El mensaje es claro, la clave del usuario `levantiu_levantium_app` que le estás pasando no es correcta, o ese usuario no existe. ¿Con qué código funciona exactamente el mismo que tenías antes?

Comment: @A.Cedano a funcionado ya! efectivamente, el mensaje es bastante claro pero no funcionaba y por ssh si funcionaba, pero ya sin tocar anda ha funcionado... esto es increíble jajaja

Comment: Y usa claves más largas. Si observas, el mensaje de error revela la clave que estás usando. Si la clave fuese larga, de 30 - 50 caracteres, se vería truncada. Y ten cuidado con el manejo de errores, si te equivocas PDO puede terminar escribiendo tus credenciales en un log de errores. Esos archivos son los preferidos de los intrusos para hackear sitios o bases de datos.

Comment: Es extraño. Pienso que hay algo que antes no ponías y que ahora pusiste. No creo que deje de funcionar y de repente por magia funcione. A no ser que tengas un hosting muy malo que haga cosas como esas.

Comment: @A.Cedano mi conclusion es que el hosting de seguro no habia corrido algun proceso, el hosting es A2hosting, la clave solo es de prueba... Gracias por su tiempo !

Comment: @A.Cedano El soporte técnico me respondió hace poco, fueron ellos que lo resolvieron, agregue la captura del mensaje en la pregunta.

Comment: Ok, gracias. Me alegro de que se haya resuelto. Saludos.